# Margin (feed_margin) problem with brother_ql from Python

Tags: python, printing, feed, margins

I have a script that uses the [brother_ql](https://pypi.org/project/brother-ql/) module to print out stickers.

The script creates an appropriately sized PNG file (width of 696px, and the height varies depending on the template). The PNG is then sent to the Brother QL-820NWB printer. Everything works fine except that the top and bottom of the sticker have an additional margin added to them.

The width looks correct, but the length has extra padding on the top and bottom. I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
from brother_ql.conversion import convert
from brother_ql.backends.helpers import send
from brother_ql.raster import BrotherQLRaster

def print_label_from_png(png_in, delete_after_print=True):
    printerdata_model = 'QL-820NWB'

    qlr = BrotherQLRaster(printerdata_model)
    qlr.exception_on_warning = True
    #qlr.mlength = 0 # Trying to kill the margins
    #qlr.mlength(0) # Trying to kill the margins
    #qlr.mwidth = 0     # Trying to kill the margins

    instructions = convert(
            qlr=qlr, 
            images=[png_in],    #  Takes a list of file names or PIL objects.
            label='62red',
            rotate='auto',      # 'Auto', '0', '90', '270'
            threshold=70.0,     # Black and white threshold in percent.
            dither=False, 
            compress=False, 
            red=True,           # Only True if using Red/Black 62 mm label tape.
            dpi_600=False, 
            hq=True,            # False for low quality.
            cut=True
    )
    
    # The "feed_margin" data is taken from the label. In this case, the "62red" has a margin of 35. This is then called in convert() where: qlr.add_margins(label_specs['feed_margin'])
    # I tried to then set it here with 0, but it seems to do nothing...
    qlr.add_margins(0) 
    qlr.mlength = 0
    
    
    it_worked = send_data_to_printer(instructions) # This just adds the printer IP and tells it to send the request via the network.
    if (delete_after_print): os.remove(png_in)
    return it_worked
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Unfortunately it's **not physically possible** to eliminate margin feed when using automatic cutting as the tape needs to be fed forward in order to be cut (because the cutting unit is not in the same location as the printing head), which adds a margin to the next tape to be printed.
2. You're right that the `feed_margin` attribute is set on a per-label-type basis. You **can** modify it however, as the label information is stored in a global variable that's initialized only once:

```py
from brother_ql.devicedependent import label_type_specs

# [...]

label_type_specs["62red"]["feed_margin"] = 0 # modify settings of label type "62red"
instructions = convert( # ...
```

3. I've tested this with a QL-700, but it does not seem to work even though the `convert` method receives the correct margin-parameter, as the printer itself requires/adds a margin for cutting, as described in (1).
4. `.add_margins(0)`  is the method called by `convert` to add margins to the print-output (i.e. the "instructions") so calling it can only add additional margins to the output, not remove existing ones that were already added by the `convert` method

Comment: I thought this may be the case, except for the fact that when the printer has done a configuration print it has printed a thin line and cut the sticker to about 3-4mm. 

I'm thinking now that it was more of a random quirk than something that can be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure by your question what margins you refer to.
I managed to remove the white space for the width (the 62mm dimension in op question) by changing the dots_printable attribute.
so much like the example above I updated the label definition for a 29mm type:

```
from brother_ql.devicedependent import label_type_specs

# [...]

label_type_specs["29x90"]["dots_printable"] = (336, 991) # modify settings of label type "29x90"
instructions = convert( # ...
```

The original size was (306,991) and I did find that changing the y dimension isn't good since that will cause a cut in the wrong place.